# Phonegap build android not finding cordova

Tags: android, cordova

When I try to execute `phonegap build android` in my terminal I get the following error: 
`error:cannot find .cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/create no such file or directory`

I am able to navigate to `.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/`, however I do not have anything beyond that. I have tried to execute `npm install cordova` and it seems to download and install cordova, but it does not make a bin folder.

I am using mac os x 10.9. Does anyone have any idea for why phonegap will not find cordova?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Once I removed the .cordova directory and executed `npm install cordova` again, it worked correctly.